# Calling an unmanaged DLL from C# passing structs as parameters

Tags: c#, delphi, dll, unmanaged

I have a DLL file for which I have no type library and no documentation. What I do have is Delphi (Pascal) code that is using it. I am trying to call this DLL using .Net 5 C#.

The error I get is

> System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'

Here is my attempt:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MyDLLQuery
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
        public string Frame;

        public int Width { get; set; }

        public double Cost { get; set; }
        ...
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MyDLLResult
    {
        public int NumTubes { get; set; }
        public double Spacing { get; set; }

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
        public string Material;
        ...
    }

    internal static class MyDLLWrapper
    {
        const string DLL = @"bin\MyDLL.dll";
        private static CallbackDelegate delegateInstance;

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public delegate void CallbackDelegate();
    
        [DllImport(DLL, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private static extern void CalculateData(MyDLLQuery indata, out MyDLLResult outdata, CallbackDelegate f);

        internal static void Query()
        {
            MyDLLQuery indata = new MyDLLQuery();
            indata.Frame = "G";
            indata.Width = 1300; 
            indata.Cost = 50.0; 
            ...

            MyDLLResult outdata = new MyDLLResult();
    
            delegateInstance = MyFunc;
    
            CalculateData(indata, out outdata, delegateInstance);
        }

        public static void MyFunc()
        {
            
        }
    }
```

Here is the Delphi code calling the same DLL (that does work):

```
    TInParams = record
        Frame: array [0..15] of Char;
        Width: Integer;
        Cost: Double;
        ...

    TOutParams = record
        NumTubes: Integer;
        Spacing: Double;
        Material: array [0..15] of Char;
        ...


    TInfoCallBackProcedure = procedure() cdecl;

    const LIBNAME = 'MyDLL.dll';

    procedure CalculateData(InData: TInParams; var OutData: TOutParams; Callback: TInfoCallbackProcedure); stdcall external LIBNAME;


    var
        InParams: TInParams;
        OutParams: TOutParams;


    SetInData(sourceData, InParams); // assigns a value to all fields in InParams
    FillChar(OutParams, SizeOf(OutParams), 0);

    CalculateData(InParams, OutParams, Callback); // No callback = nil
```

I've made sure all the fields in the structs are in the same order as in the Delphi code.

Comment: Calling convention need to be CallingConvention.Cdecl (not StdCall) if you are going from c#to c language.  Stdcall is going to Fortran or Basic.

Comment: I tried this, same result. I suspect that the DLL is written in Pascal.

Comment: Check the pascal compiling option.  It can use either standard or c convention.

Comment: Check sizes of integers in pascal which may not be 32 bits.  Also check string types if they are 8 bit, 16 bit, or combination.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-strings?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng Integer in Delphi is 32 bit, maps to int in C#. Calling convention of the exported function is stdcall, explicitly declared in the code. This is a question where knowledge of Delphi is critical.

Comment: @Niklas the only thing that I can see that could be wrong is that delphi char could be 8 bit AnsiChar or 16 bit WideChar depending on the Delphi version. Of course there could be other errors in the code we can't see.  But it seems to me that you know what you are doing here.

Comment: This is somewhat new territory for me so what you see above is simply my best guess after reading stackoverflow and banging my head on my desk for a while.

Comment: You could try to provide just a huge chunk of memory as output (and eventually also as input) structures. That way you could rule out problems with the library overwriting data past the end of the structure, which causes this exception to be generated. Depending on the memory management in delphi, a buffer overrun in the library might not cause a crash there.

Comment: Did you try passing `null` for the callback (the Delphi code says the callback is optional)?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe the declaration would be more accurate as `ref MyDLLResult outdata` instead of `out`.  But I don't know if that would change anything to your situation.

Comment: @Ken that would better match var but since the intent seems to be to return the result then out may be correct and the Delphi is not accurate. It won't change how the arg is passed, as a pointer to the struct.

Comment: I did try with null callback. I also tried with ref instead of out. No luck. 
@PMF I'm not really sure how to do that, any tips?

Comment: You can do what pmf says for the ref param by passing a caller allocated byte array. But you can't do it for the input parameter passed by value. For all we know there is a mistake in the code we can't see. And we still have no idea what char is in the Delphi DLL. Unless you provide full details this question has run its course.

Comment: @NiklasJonsson Change the input/output parameter types to `void*` and pass a variable you allocated using `Marshal.AllocHGlobal()` or a `fixed` declaration.

Comment: @PMF that would require unsafe. Trivial to do it the way I said. Doesn't help with the input parameter.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Good point: maybe really the problem is with the input argument. Generally we would expect any class or struct type to be passed by reference to an external function. IIRC Pascal really has by-value semantics if `var` is not specified, but what it does with an external declaration. I have no clue. One could try it the other way round, by seeing what happens if the input parameter is also passed as ref. Maybe looking at the library signature using dependency walker could give a hint.

Comment: @pmf it will pass it on the stack for a 32 bit dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved this. I had tried with Charset unicode on the DLL call previously, but I had missed setting it on the structs:

```
[DllImport(DLL, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern void CalculateData(MyDLLQuery indata, out MyDLLResult outdata, CallbackDelegate f);
```

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct MyDLLQuery
...

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct MyDLLResult
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct Result
    {
        //SizeCount bezieht sich anscheinden auf Char (hier 2 Byte) und
        // nicht auf die Bytegröße des Felds
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 12)] public string BIC; //Delphi: array[0..10] of char
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 35)] public string IBAN; //Delphi: array[0..33] of char
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] public BACIbanKonverterStatus Status;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 201)] public string StatusMessage;
        //Delphi: array[0..199] of char

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] //Delphi: Longbool
        public bool Success;
    }
```

Has been implemented in Delphi as follows :

```
 TRecIban=packed record
public
  Bic          : array[0..10] of char;
  Filler_1     : Char;
  Iban         : array[0..33] of char;
  Filler_2     : Char;
  Status       : integer;
  StatusMessage: array[0..199] of char;
  Filler_3     : Char;
  Success      : Longbool;
end
```

The end of the string in C # is mapped to the *Filler_X* in Delphi. Today I would marshal over *[MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]* in C #. In Delphi I would use a *PChar*. Then the filler is unnecessary.